# Android ActionBar or Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I've been reading/youtubing a lot about how I should start my next app and found out that the activities suggested as start activities in Android Studio may contain deprecated elements such as the ActionBar, and that I should rather start from scratch without an activity, and use the newly lollipop-introduced "Toolbar".

My question is: As I need a top bar of a kind (ActionBar/Toolbar) and a navigation drawer in my app, should I invest the time it needs to build the Toolbar opposed to starting with a NavigationDrawer activity from the beggining?

Will using an NavigationDrawer activity (with an ActionBar) mean that I'm staring a new app with old-fashioned kind of top bar?

Comment: No no ToolBar just introduced in Lollipop doesn't mean ActionBar's gonna look old fashioned. You can make app with ActionBar.

Comment: The main question here is what is your minimal API target? Before Android 3, there is no ActionBar.

Comment: My minimal target will be 14 (Android 4.0), so it should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very first thing ActionBar is not deprecated and not old style component. It still serves the purpose well. Toolbar only comes into existence when you need more than ActionBar, for instance, you want to increase the height of ActionBar and want to inflate some custom views then ActionBar might not be a right choice. If you just need an Activity with NavigationDrawer, I don't think so you need a ToolBar at all. Just create a new project from scratch and pick NavigationDrawer as a pre-configured option while creating the project and you are good to go. ActionBar is not going anywhere, at least for now. Hope it would help.